# Binary Counting

Tags: ms-access, binary-tree, counting

my data structure is like this:

```
+-------------+------+-------+
| USERID (PK) | LEFT | RIGHT |
+-------------+------+-------+
|     001     |      |  002  |
|     002     | 003  |  004  |
|     003     | 005  |       |
|     004     |      |       |
|     005     | 008  |  007  |
|     008     |      |       |
|     007     | 009  |       |
|     009     |      |       |
+-------------+------+-------+
```

This data structure represents a binary tree. Each row represents a node, each having a `USERID`. The entries in the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` columns represent the two children of that node by referring them with `USERID`s. I want to traverse this tree.

I am using Visual Studio 2005 with an Access database.

Comment: -1 Because Every Word Starts With A Capital And It Is Very Annoying To Try And Figure Out What You Are Trying To Say.

Comment: Try. using. some. punctuation. as. well,

Comment: I have tried editing the question so that it's easier to read, but you're still missing quite a bit of information - like what language you're using and how you want to traverse the tree (i.e. what is the expected order of traversal?). In the future, please try to format and phrase your questions for readability.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I can come up with is that you've picked completely the wrong way of representing your data.

A far more sensible way to represent the user ids is as a simple column in (I guess) the table that holds the details for the users, with an index to give you fast lookup.  Then "traversal" degenerates to a simple select and iterating over the resultset.

If you want to proceed with your current (IMO silly) table structure, then SQL is not going to help you to do traversal of the tree.  If you try to traverse the tree in the database, you'll end up doing a select for each node in the tree which will be horribly slow.

Your best bet is to select all rows of the table, construct a tree in memory, and traverse that tree.

Comment: I am sorry following a stupid method, now i got understand, before completing this project first of i would like to go through "Tree Transversal concept". I searched on internet and got lots of article regarding this, can you suggest me some good books regarding algorithm computation.

Comment: @Harie James - There are many, many books on "data structures and algorithms" for different programming languages.  Try searching on amazon.com, and browsing the contents and sample chapters with the "Look Inside" feature.